# Email Syncing problems

Tags: macos, ios, data-synchronization, email

Why does my email not sync on my Mac if I have read it on my iPhone or iPad? I can read it in my iPhone or Mac, but it does not show as read on my Mac.

Comment: What type of email account do you have? IMAP/POP/Exchange/Etc.

Comment: Yahoo mail, its IMAP or POP

Answer (score 1):

POP does not sync your "read" information (and various other things)

Yahoo does not allow IMAP access, according to the customer response quoted on this link: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070630193312AAmgjq0